# How can I model log in database?

Tags: python, database, logging, model

I have a system which allows user to upload video to Youtube while I keep a log in my database, the problem right now is that I have no idea how can I model it.

Using databases's log system(I use Django's ORM) proved to be too verbose since I need to generate nicely formatted pages to allow the 'manager' users to see the user's activity.

Right now I have two options:

**First :**

[image]

Use foreign keys and a field to indicate type.
Pros:

- simple implementation

Cons:

- Extra works when I have to query logs

**Second :**
[image]

Use inheritance to split the log into 3 part: Create, Update, and Delete.
A create must exists to have a Video entry to exist, A video entry is deleted if it has a delete log.

Pros:

- Easy logic on programming side

Cons:

- complex model implementation, could be inflexible for future extension.

I am not sure, which one is better? or I get all this problem wrong?(like there's already a pattern for this kind of problem?)

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to create logs in your database, rather than in log files? If you need to report on the data, there are good tools available for giving you real-time data on your log files. Try Splunk or Graphite.

Comment: The log is for client(i.e. the 'manager' user) which is not 'tech-savy'. And I want to generate nice report page when users are viewing the video entry to see the modification history. Thanks for comment though, although that's probably not exactly I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't see any advantage in the second option. Can you elaborate why you consider that?

Comment: I use Django ORM. so, for example, to see the video entry is created by which uploader, just type `video.createlog.uploader`. First option I need to search through logs and pinpoint the log with creation.

Through just find the earliest log would be suffice i suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For instance at first variant you can create 3 additional `QueryManager` for your `Log` model and use them (it will be similar to the 2 variant but without creating 3 additional models).

They can be like `create_objects`, `update_objects` and `delete_objects` or more shorter (for example `create_log`).

Here is example of manager class:

```
from django.db.models import Manager

class LogManager(Manager):
    def __init__(self, type):
        super(LogManager, self).__init__()
        # add check of type if you need
        self._type = type

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(LogManager, self).get_queryset().filter(type=self._type)
```

This code is only for demonstration (I didn't test it).

And in your model class you should specify 3 additional managers like this:

```
from django.db.models import Model

class Log(Model):
    create_log = LogManager('create')
    update_log = LogManager('update')
    delete_log = LogManager('delete')
```

Or you can use `__getattr__` method to get appropriate manager but "Explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: Thank you, I am still new to django/python, dunno I can do that.